# How to get the most dependent stored procedure in SQL Server using T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014, sqldependency

I am trying to get the most dependent stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio 2014. I have a huge database which has almost 1900 stored procedures, 453 tables, 768 views and 419 functions altogether. Some of the stored procedures are very big (4089 lines) which is nested with many stored procedures, views and functions. I want to redesign the architecture and the software itself.

I want to get the report of the most dependent stored procedure with the dependent object name.

I have searched for it but I have not get a appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [sys.sql_expression_dependencies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677315.aspx) system view.

However, if you are indeed to understand the structure of the code modules hierarchy, you will definitely need some sort of visualisation tool to display the dependency graph as a diagram. Haven't heard about anything on the market that will suit your needs, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can find them through below process. I have tested our DB with just 149 stored procedures and took 1 min time to fetch.

Here i am passing Stored procedure name to object_DEFINITION function to know in which procedure definition having this name used.

```
    DECLARE @TAB_SP TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, OBJECTID int, NAME VARCHAR(250))
    DECLARE @TAB_SP_DEPENDENCY TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, NAME VARCHAR(250), SP_COUNT INT)

    INSERT INTO @TAB_SP
    select object_id,NAME from sys.objects WHERE type='P'

    DECLARE @MIN INT =1, @MAX INT = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @TAB_SP), @SP_NAME VARCHAR(250)

    WHILE (@MIN<=@MAX)
    BEGIN

            SELECT @SP_NAME=NAME  FROM @TAB_SP WHERE ID= @MIN

            INSERT INTO @TAB_SP_DEPENDENCY
            SELECT @SP_NAME,COUNT(DISTINCT object_id) FROM SYS.OBJECTS 
            WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) LIKE '%'+@SP_NAME+'%'

            SET @MIN=@MIN+1
    END

    SELECT * FROM @TAB_SP_DEPENDENCY
```

Comment: this result in two row not list of sp and functions. Following is the result                                                         object_id   and          NAME values are
{1803153469, sp_MSrepl_startup}{
1819153526, sp_MScleanupmergepublisher}